# React ChartJS empty state axios call

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-chartjs

I am trying to paint crypto coin from api in ChartJS. Axios call is going well object with key value pairs are fetch. But when i want to setState to push them into chart (data property) and i am logging my state it only return two empty arrays of Datasets and labels

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import Chart from "./components/Chart";
import axios from "axios";
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    chartData: {}
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getChartData();
  }

  getChartData() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR"
      )
      .then(res => {
        const coin = res.data;
        const result = Object.values(coin)[0];
        this.setState({
          chartData: {
            labels: [
              "Boston",
              "Worcester",
              "Springfield",
              "Lowell",
              "Cambridge",
              "New Bedford"
            ],
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Population",
                data: result,
                backgroundColor: [
                  "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)",
                  "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)",
                  "rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)",
                  "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)",
                  "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)",
                  "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.6)",
                  "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        });
      });
    console.log(this.state);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <Chart
          chartData={this.state.chartData}
          location="Massachusetts"
          legendPosition="bottom"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

setState doesn't setState synchronously any more, so you might be better off putting your  `console.log(this.state);` in `render()`.

You'll notice that `render()` gets called twice. Once for initial render, and a second time once setState actually sets the state.

I'd add a variable to track the axios call's `loading` state in your `render()` function, and once done loading, render your chart.

Edit:
Simplest solution would just be to render nothing until data is ready:

```
render() {
    if(!this.state.chartData.datasets[0].data){return null}
    else {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <Chart
              chartData={this.state.chartData}
              location="Massachusetts"
              legendPosition="bottom"
            />
          </div>
        );
    }     
}
```

Comment: hey can you please post edited code? but i think from this api call i am setting empty state to chart component so chart is drawn but without data

Comment: not working i console.log props passed into Chart.js copmponet and props has empty array of data. So I am console logging data in App.js but this is not send to Chart.js. but!!! other props are sent like labels